# Using CouchDB with Laravel 4 in a 3-tier app

Tags: couchdb, laravel, 3-tier

I'v been searching hardly these past days in how to use CouchDB in the 2-tier, I haven't found a properly documented and useful resource (Doctrine's CouchDB ODM seems very vague I think), so the question is: How are you using CouchDB in your app, obfuscating the access to the users? I really don't think that is wise to use  CouchDB on the first tier! I found some packages on Packagist but with little to none documentation about the usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out Sag: http://www.saggingcouch.com/

It's a deliberately simplistic PHP (with a matching JS) client library for interfacing with CouchDB. It doesn't (by design) provide ORM or extra "magic" preferring to give you simple access to the CouchDB API.

Hope that helps.